# Android Pattern matcher failed to detect a special character

Tags: android, regex

My Requirement is to accept string input that ha 3-50 chars and can only contains alphanumeric, spaces(middle only), and a hyphen.

Here is my TestCase

```
class TestInput {

    @Test
    fun testUsernameValidation() {

        println("Testing Valid UserName")

        val tests =  arrayOf(
            "HelL&",
            "HelL&&",
            "HelL+&^% w0rld~",
            "hello-the|_++)_%re",
            " Sample",
            "sh",
            "slugging-patternsSLUGGING-pattern",
            "sipletext"
        )

        tests.forEach {
            println("${it.isValidUserName()}\t$it")
        }
    }
}
```

And my extension

```
fun String.isValidUserName(): Boolean {
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "[^\\s]" +
        "[a-zA-Z 0-9\\-]{0,50}" +
        "[^\\s]" )

    return this.length in 3..50
        && pattern.matcher(this).matches()
}
```

this test produce the result:

```
Testing Valid UserName
true    HelL&
false   HelL&&
false   HelL+&^% w0rld~
false   hello-the|_++)_%re
false    Sample
false   sh
true    slugging-patternsSLUGGING-pattern
true    sipletext
```

The only problem is the first string that only contains 1 special character returns true. Is there anything wrong with the Pattern i have created?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem is the first and last part of the pattern [^\s] indicating that it accepts anything except white spaces.

I have changed the pattern this way and now it works.

```
fun String.isValidUserName(): Boolean {
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1}" +
        "[a-zA-Z 0-9\\-]{0,50}" +
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1}" 
    )

    return this.length in 3..50
        && pattern.matcher(this).matches()
}
```